# xp_cmdshell not generating the file on specified location

Tags: sql-server, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I'm using xp_cmdshell bcp to generate CSV file from the output, But I'm not able to generate the file, it gives me following output when executed.

I get this as the output, I'm not sure what is going on as I do not have much of hands on using xp_cmdshell
I see there is something to do with -l login timeout, but not sure what is the time out

[image]

Below is the query I'm running

```
BCP "Select * FROM #temp" queryout "F:\Share\Test\test.csv" -c -t "|" -T -S<ServerName>
```

I'm expecting csv file with the result containing pipe separated values

Comment: You'll need to include your SQL code that is building the bcp statement you are passing to xp_cmdshell. The output you are seeing is what BCP gives you when bad command is issued.

Comment: The command you have listed here seems fine, so the question is if what you shared here is actually what is being sent to BCP via xp_cmdshell. Include your SQL code that is build the BCP command and that is calling xp_cmdshell